# How do I catch the referer URL in my session before embarking on an authentication with Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth

I'm using Rails 5.  I'm using the Omniauth gem (but not Devise) for authentication with the following sites (from my Gemfile) ...

```
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
```

I have links on my page that look like

```
<%= link_to image_tag("google_plus_icon.jpg", :height => 50, :border => 0, :alt => 'Google', :title => 'Google', :class => 'loginImg'), '/auth/google' %>
```

My question is, right before the authentication sequence begins with the external service, I would like to catch the HTTP Referer header in my session.  I would like to record this when the user clicks on the link but before the authentication sequence begins.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet here would be to do a few things:

**Without Devise**

I would add a block that will run during the setup phase for your strategy. You'll need to add this to every strategy you want to configure.

https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase

```
SETUP_PROC = lambda do |env| 
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  session = request.env['rack.session']
  session[:preauth_referrer] ||= request.referrer
end

use OmniAuth::Builder.new do
  provider :google, :setup => SETUP_PROC
end
```

You'll probably need to restart your application server after changing the configuration code.

**With Devise**

1. Override the OmniauthCallbacksController if you haven't already

   ```
   class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
   end

   # Then in routes.rb, as detailed at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/omniauth:-overview
   devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
   ```
2. Add a before_filter in the new controller you just created. The passthrough method is used by the /auth/:provider endpoint by default.

   ```
   prepend_before_action :store_referrer, only: [:passthrough]
   ```
3. Store the referrer in the session. This is necessary because you haven't authenticated your user yet

   ```
   session[:preauth_referrer] = request.referrer
   ```

So the full controller would look something like the following:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  prepend_before_filter :store_referrer, only: [:passthrough]

  # Other overrides go here, for example overriding the callback methods

  private
    def store_referrer
      session[:preauth_referrer] = request.referrer
    end
end
```

Then when the user comes back from the authentication redirect you can associate the referrer with the user in persistent storage if you like.

As a footnote, I would recommend using the rails route url helpers instead of referencing the path directly, so something like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("google_plus_icon.jpg", :height => 50, :border => 0, :alt => 'Google', :title => 'Google', :class => 'loginImg'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(provider: :google) %>
```

Comment: Hi, Actually I'm not using Devise.  I edited my question to reflect htis.

Comment: Updated my answer to handle the non-devise use case. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  I was out of town but now as I try and implement this one quesiton occurred -- where do I put the code (the file path) for the setup method you listed?

Comment: You can create an initializer (e.g. _config/initializers/omniauth.rb_) and follow the configuration instructions here: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth.

Instead of just "use" you may need to use the full configuration reference:

**Rails.application.config.middleware.use**